# Reports on .Net and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My client wants a report with some bars/charts to analysis his data.

So how do I give him this type of reports as iam using .NET 1.1 and sql server 2008..

Is this requirement possible with BI, with .net1.1?

Or there is some other solution for this type of requirement?

Please send ur suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SQL Server Reporting Services? Although it does depend on which version of SQL Server your client has.